# Steam game from Mac to PC

Tags: steam, macos, windows, rome-2-total-war, steam-play

Im using a Macbook right now and I bought Rome 2 Total War with Steam, however I've just bought a new gaming laptop which is Windows.

I wonder if I'm able to download my game on my new laptop from Steam? I do know that Rome 2 Total War works fine on both OS's

Thans for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you bought the game on Steam, it is tied to your account and should be available for you to download on other platforms. That's what the "SteamPlay" icon on the [store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/214950/) means.

Comment: I'd like to emphesise that this is not generaly true, only for games that have the said SteamPlay enabled. Otherwise you'd need to buy another version of the game, if available.

Comment: Actually its more likely than not that a game that is on both Mac and PC is steam play enabled. Especially with newer titles. Also depending on the title cloud saving may allow you to access you save game data across both platforms.